# PHP get endpoint works locally, but not on server

Tags: php, mysql

I've written an endpoint in PHP to query a mysql database and return results in a JSON format - It works locally, but not when i deploy to AWS.

Here's the url for the hosted version: http://www.everythingproduct.com/getArticlesTest.php?type=All

and here's the code;

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Assign the post values to variables
// Types of request - E.g. 'All', 'Article' or a 'Tag-Search'
$type = $_GET["type"];

// If a specific article, what article?
$article  = $_GET["article"];

// If a tag-search, what tag used?
$tag  = $_GET["tag"];

// Define database parameters
$servername = "***********.cl8bq5gds2sn.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306";
$username = "********";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "*********";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

If ($type == 'All') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY datetime desc LIMIT 10";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
} elseif ($type == 'Article') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = " . $article;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
} elseif ($type == 'Tag-search') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tags like '%" . $tag . "%' ORDER BY datetime desc LIMIT 10";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

// Put the results into an array, and echo some json

$resultArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($resultArray, array(
            'id' => $row["id"],
            'datetime' => $row["datetime"],
            'source' => utf8_encode($row["source"]),
            'title' => utf8_encode($row["title"]),
            'description' => utf8_encode($row["description"]),
            'img' => $row["img"],
            'link' => $row["link"],
            'tags' => $row["tags"]
        )
    );
}


$resultArray = json_encode($resultArray);
echo $resultArray;

?>
```

Ignoring the obvious security stuff (which i'm aware of), I can't understand why I just get a 504 gateway timeout from the hosted version, but the localhost works perfectly.

[image: Json displayed on localhost]

[image: 504 Gateway on hosted version]

Comment: Have you tested the connection between the hosted version and the database, as well as accounted for the time it takes your local version to execute the queries, against the time the hosted version takes?

Comment: I haven't tested connect of hosted to database as i can't get the page to load (I'll create a simplified db connection php page in a sec to do that). But i was thinking the issue is likely to do with the AWS permissions... i'm investigating that also.

Comment: what you have in error log?

Comment: There are no error logs... it's just a 504 timeout, making it difficult to debug. I checked the AWS permission and the RDS instances is set to public so anyone can connect to it.

Comment: Elastic beanstalk logs jsut shows the following; [Sun Oct 22 01:58:06.859939 2017] [php7:warn] [pid 28798] [client 172.31.34.231:5161] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /var/app/current/website/getArticlesTest2.php on line 13

Comment: So you probably need to add an entry in [one of] the security groups that are attached to the mysql instance, allowing MySQL/Aurora from the instance that runs the PHP.

Comment: I thought that too... but if the RDS is publicly accessible, doesn't that mean that i don't need to to worry about security groups as any can access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Had to change AWS inbound rules for the security group associated with the RDS to accept traffic from the EC2 instance.